# How do I determine the number of CPU cores the PC has?

Tags: sas

How do I determine the number of CPU cores the PC using code? Is there a way to do it in SAS. I want to determine the number of cores and then set how many threads I should run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SAS:

```
%put &sysncpu;
```

In java one would do:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
int nrOfProcessors = runtime.availableProcessors();
```

In C#:

```
System.Environment.ProcessorCount
```

But these are just environment variables which are set by the operating system and can probably be modified through programming. I don't know if you can actually get real hardware information.

Comment: One thing to note is that I am using a Core i7 920 which is hpyerthreading and &sysncpu gives me 8 cpu threads where as i only have 4 cpu cores. Wonder if there is a further variables to determine the number of cores i have.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to know the number of physical CPU's. If there is some way to determine whether HT is enabled or not, you can simply divide by the value by 2 (you may be able to find some quick-&-dirty scripts for that).

Answer (score 3):

There is an automatic macro variable called SYSNCPU that gives you the number of CPUs; not sure if this is the figure you're after?

Answer (score 1):

**Delphi**:

```
function TSpinLockPerProcReaderWriterLock.NumberProcessors: Integer;
var
    systemInfo: SYSTEM_INFO;
begin
    GetSystemInfo({var}systemInfo);
    Result := systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
end;
```

Transcoded into a C# style pseudo-language:

```
int NumberProcessors()
{
   SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;

   GetSystemInfo(ref systemInfo);
   return systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 0):

This code will tell you, within the constraints of `CPUCOUNT=` for your version of `SAS`. Example documentation https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lesysoptsref/p14arc7flhenwqn1v1gipt9e49om.htm

```
OPTION CPUCOUNT=ACTUAL;
PROC OPTIONS GROUP=PERFORMANCE;
RUN;
```

> ...**CPUCOUNT=8**     Specifies the number of processors that thread-enabled applications should assume are available for concurrent processing....